# android - creating generic interface for two List wrappers

Tags: java, list, generics, types, interface

I have to perform similar methods on two types of lists.

```
private List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurations;
private List<ScanResult> mScanResults;
```

I need to scan both lists and look for some specific item, so I figured I'll create an interface to wrap them up, and then implement each `doesListContains` method.

```
public interface IWifiListWrapper {
    boolean doesListContains(IWifiInfo wifiInfo);
    //  <T> void setList(List<T> wifiList);
}
```

And one implementation for example is:

```
public class ScanResultsListWrapper implements IWifiListWrapper {

    private List<ScanResult> mScanResults;

    @Override
    public boolean doesListContains(IWifiInfo wifiInfo) {
       ...
    } 
}
```

That's all good.

Now, I also need to have a `setList` method to set the list in each of the implementations to their specific List types (`WifiConfiguration` and `ScanResult`).

It looks like is should be implemented with **Generics** somehow, but I am not really sure How do I do it.. I do need to somehow declare each list in the beginning with its Type, correct? so I can pass a matching `List` type.

How should I go about it?

Comment: Why not use method type parameters instead?

Comment: Why not like this? `public static <T> boolean doesListContain(List<T> list, T value){...}`?

Comment: But do those types extend or implement `IWifiInfo`?

Comment: no, the types don't extend IWifiInfo. IWifiInfo just holds some info that I'll compare to the List's item info. can any of you give me a code example? should it be with an interface or just a generic class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IWifiListWrapper<T> {
    boolean doesListContains(IWifiInfo wifiInfo);
    void setList(List<T> wifiList);
}
```

You can also add restrictions to type like `T extends WifiInfo`.

```
public class ScanResultsListWrapper implements IWifiListWrapper<ScanResult>      {
    private List<ScanResult> mScanResults;

    @Override
    public boolean doesListContains(IWifiInfo wifiInfo) {    
        ...
    } 
    @Override
    public void setList(List<ScanResult> wifiList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this was exactly what I was looking for. when in the syntax I can add the restrictions for T ?

Comment: In interface declaration `public interface IWifiListWrapper<T extends WifiInfo>`